# Latex Beamer - dots showing the current slide

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I'm doing a presentation, I would like to know if it's possible to make the little dots appear like a continuous line. The are jumping after 4 or 2 dots. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{UFAM}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage{movie15} %to insert GIF images

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{15,52,112}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{animate}

\usepackage[lined,ruled,boxed]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{comment}
%usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
% citations
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\def\citeapos#1{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsubsection*{\bibname } }

\title[]{}


\author[]{ \inst{1} \and  \inst{1} \and  \inst{2}}

\institute[]{\inst{1}  \and %
                      \inst{2} }


\date{\today}
\titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{ufam.eps}}


\subject{Subject}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\stepcounter{subsection}
\subsection[Contextualization]{Contextualization}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contextualization}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{robotarm2.jpg}
    \caption{Use of Robot Arm. Source: The New York Times}
    \label{fig:robotarm}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contextualization}
\begin{center}
  \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,width=1\linewidth]{10}{PD6B-AW-ARM-Large-Drone/PD6B-AW-ARM-Large-Drone-}{0}{49}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\textcolor[RGB]{24,44,155}{GIF:} Use of UAV. Source: Robotic Gizmos
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contextualization}
\begin{itemize}
    \item ;
    %\pause
    \item .
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection[Aim]{Aim}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Aim}
\begin{itemize}
\item ;%\pause
\item ;%\pause 
\item .
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Methodology}
\stepcounter{subsection}
\subsection[System's Architecture]{System's Architecture}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{System's Architecture}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{sysArch.eps}
    \caption{System's Architecture.}
    \label{fig:sysArch}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\subsection[Application Scenario]{Application Scenario}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Application Scenario}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{useCase.eps}
    \caption{Case Study Representation.}
    \label{fig:casestudy}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\subsection[Mission Planners]{Mission Planners}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Mission Planners}
\framesubtitle{Planner 1}

\end{frame}

\subsection[Optimization Problem Model]{Optimization Problem Model}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Optimization Problem Model}

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:optproblem}
    \begin{array}{ccc}
        \min & C_{mission},  \\
  \\
        \textrm{ s.t. } & \sum_{i=1}^{M}{\sum_{j=1}^{N}{x_{ij}}}=1, \\
        & C_{mission}\leq C_{max}
 \\
    \end{array}
\end{equation}  
\end{frame}

\subsection[Planner Evaluation Methodology]{Planner Evaluation Methodology}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Planner Evaluation Methodology}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:MPCI}
    MPCI_X=\frac{c_o}{c_X},
\end{equation}

Where $0 \leq MPCI_X \leq 1$.   
\end{frame}

\section{Experimental Evaluation}
\stepcounter{subsection}


\section{Summary}
\stepcounter{subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle<presentation>{Summary}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I don't want like this:

[image: latex beamer]

```
    % Based on: http://people.stern.nyu.edu/padamopo/blog/2013-02-10-latex-template.html

\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\mode<presentation>

%\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usecolortheme{orchid}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,footline=authortitle]{miniframes}   

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.471,0.008,0.412}
\definecolor{middlegreen}{rgb}{0.663,0.012,0.580}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.855,0.016,0.749}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{254,232,0}
\definecolor{ufamgreen}{RGB}{24,42,22}
\definecolor{lightufamgreen}{RGB}{64,160,54}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=ufamgreen}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=darkgray}

\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=white,bg=gray} %subsection
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=white,bg=ufamgreen} %section

\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}         %Title of presentation
\setbeamercolor{section title}{fg=white, bg=ufamgreen}
\setbeamercolor{subsection title}{fg=white, bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=lightgray}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=gray, bg=white}


\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\mode
<all>
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with a simple test document https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CoiO.png, please show us some code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes @samcarter, I want something like you have shown in the image.

Comment: The `UFAM` need to pass the option`compress` to the miniframes theme. Is the `UFAM` available somewhere?

Comment: @samcarter, I just put it here. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the new line for each new subsection by using the option `compress` for your theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{UFAM}

\begin{document}

\section{Summary}
\subsection{test1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{test2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

---

A few additional points about your document:

- you don't nee `\usepackage{graphicx}` with `beamer`
- using floating specifier in a document class that does not have floats does not really make sense, so you can remove the `[H]` for all your figures.

Comment: Thanks you very much @samcarter. I will add all of these.